# DynamoDB query without knowing the primary key

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table with 3 attributes

```
ARTICLE | CLAPS | STAMP
 -----  | ----- | ----
 RUST   |   1   | 2 OCT 2020 19:20
 C++    |   3   | 10 OCT 2020 12:30
```

I want to do these 3 queries on the table :

1. Check if the article name is taken
2. The article with highest number of claps
3. The most recent article

What is the most efficient way to query 2 and 3 without using a scan operation?

Comment: What is the table's primary key (article plus what)? Can there be multiple items for a given article (presumably yes)?

Comment: The Article is itself the primary key. There is not sort key.

Comment: So there will only ever be one article on RUST?

Comment: Yes. Think it as questions on StackOverflow. Each question is unique, has unique upvotes, timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through @Charles answer. I am taking the following approach.

TABLE

```
  POST | TYPE | CLAPS | STAMP
 ----- | ---- | ----- | ----
 RUST  |  A   |   1   | 1594185483964
 C++   |  A   |   3   | 1594185984082
```

Here TYPE `A` denotes an article.

I have made 2 GSIs.

1. Partition key Type, Sort Key CLAPS ; Index : TYPE-CLPAS-POSTS
2. Partition key Type, Sort Key STAMP ; Index : TYPE-STAMP-POSTS

I think this will increase flexibility while allowing me to do valid queries.

1. To find the article with the highest number of claps.

```js
{
  TableName: 'WB360-POSTS',
  IndexName: 'TYPE-CLAPS-POSTS',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#T = :T',
  ScanIndexForward: false,
  Limit: 10,
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
   '#T': 'TYPE'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
   ':T': 'A'
  },
  ProjectionExpression: 'POST'
}
```

2. To find the most recent article.

```js
{
  TableName: 'WB360-POSTS',
  IndexName: 'TYPE-STAMP-POSTS',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#T = :T',
  ScanIndexForward: false,
  Limit: 10,
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
   '#T': 'TYPE'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
   ':T': 'A'
  },
  ProjectionExpression: 'POST'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the most efficient way to query 2 and 3 without using a scan operation?

Create  Global Secondary Indexes (GSI)

Hash key would be either the string "CLAPS" or the string "STAMP", sort key would be the corresponding CLAPS value or the STAMP value.

When you Query(), specify '"ScanIndexForward=false"`and`"Limit=1"` to get the most highest (most recent) value.

Note you need to store the time stamp in a sortable format, "2020-10-10-12:30" not "10 OCT 2020 12:30"